# Как сделать всплывающее окно после отправки формы?

Tags: javascript

Для проверки полей формы на заполнение использую jQuery Validation Plugin.
[Пример здесь](http://lpsystem.ru/forma.html). Как сделать появление всплывающего окна сразу после отправки
формы с результатами отправки данных формы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте оттолкнуться от этого примера:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#form_id').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response); // отправлено удачно
            },
        error: function(response) {
            alert(response); // ошибка
            }
    });

});
```